# Windows 7 64bit search bar is buggered

Tags: windows-7, windows, search, cache

When I search for something in the Windows 7 Start Menu, I am only given categories.

**Screenshot:**

[image: search]

I have tried the following, to no avail:

- Deleted registry keys
- Restarted, stopped, started, reinstalled every other setting related to 
  Windows Search
- Cleared the cache
- Deleted the cache

How can I restore my Windows 7 search?

Comment: what happens when you start the search in the explorer?  Start it from a specific folder ?

Comment: Bascially the search works just about fine in explorer for files. 
I did fix the problem by restoring back but its dead annoying

Comment: for some reason , I saw this first as:  The search in that location is CD (current directory) to the wrong location?  a registry entry? an enviroment varable being damaged or getting to long (255 charachters) ?  programs love to put in thier own programs folder as path till env variable breaks.  One of those %system% things pointing wrong?

Comment: I have this same problem.

Comment: Does going into Index Options in the control panel yield a "waiting to receive index status..."?

Comment: This question is pretty old now. I have fixed this